# Eigenvalues of $n$ by $n$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Matrix A is a $n$ by $n$ matrix that has 3 different eigenvalues $a$, $b$ and $c$. 
We know that:

Eigenvalue $a$ has geometric multiplicity of 2 and algebraic multiplicity of 4.

Eigenvalue $b$ has geometric multiplicity of 3.

Eigenvalue $c$ has equal geometric multiplicity and algebraic multiplicity.

What is $n$ at least?

Comment: Hint: The algebraic multiplicity is bounded below by the geometric multiplicity, which is bounded below by $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to your information, the characteristic polynomial of your matrix is
$$
p(t) = (t-a)^4(t-b)^\beta(t-c)^\gamma
$$
with $\beta \geq 3$ and $\gamma\geq 1$. The size $n$ of the matrix is $n=4+\beta+\gamma$. You want the minimum so you have to find a matrix where $\beta=3$ and $\gamma=1$. Taking the matrix:
$$A=
\left[
\begin{matrix}
a&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&a&1&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&a&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&a&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&b&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&b&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&b&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&c\\
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

you have your conditions satisfied. So the minimum is $n=1+3+4=8$.

Comment: thank you so much for explaining this!